# How to create custom endpoints for custom post types with ACF?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-routes

I've created a custom post type with custom fields (using **Advanced Custom Fields** plugin).
I need to create different routes for each single post, using a code expressed during the creation of the post.
In particular: I have a field called '**post_code**', I need to retrieve informations about this particular post using routes like `http://my website.com/code=CODE&f=GetInfoPost` to acquire informations about that post or `http://mywebsite.com/code=CODE&f=GetCategoriesPost` to get other field values.  This '**post_code**' is chosen during the creation of the post. 
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In custom post type for rest api support while you create custom post type you need to add 'show_in_rest' => true. 
then you have to create your add_rewrite_endpoint for create your routes end point.